# bind global variable on a component with :key

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I've work on a **Vue** project, I have a login page which redirect to the Home page when the user is logged.

The thing is that I need to update/re-render the header component when the user is on the Home page.

So I've created a global variable in the main.ts:

#### Main.ts

```js
Vue.prototype.isLogin = false;
```

I use this global value as my key for my header:

#### App.vue

```html
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container">
    <e-header v-bind:key="isLogin" />
    <div class="alert-box">
      <div class="alert-list">
        <e-alert
          v-for="(notif, index) in $store.state.notifications"
          :key="index"
          :type="notif.type"
          @dismissAlert="dismissAlert(index)"
        >
          {{ notif.message }}
        </e-alert>
      </div>
    </div>
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>
```

And on the Login component, in my `login()` methods:

#### Login.vue

```js
        AdminApi.login(this.email, this.password).then(() => {
          this.loaderActive = false;
          this.isLogin = true;
        });
```

The problem is when the user login successfully and redirected on the Home page, the header component doesn't update, do I need to use **prop** instead of a global variable in my `App.vue`?

Comment: Someone with more experience than I should correct me if I'm wrong, but this sounds like it could be a reactivity issue. I'm under the impression that creating a global var like that, outside of the data object of a vue instance, means [it isn't reactive](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects). This means that Vue won't be able to tell when it changes, and I'm thinking that could cause problems with using it as a key.

Comment: so maybe if I want to create a global variable, I need to instanciate it in App.vue if I correctly understood?

Comment: You *could* add it to your App.vue `data()` and pass it down as a prop, but that could become impractical if you need it in nested components, since you'll have to pass it down as a prop to every component that needs it. Vuex state management would be more elegant a solution, though using it for a single var might feel like overkill, if this really is the only thing that you'd use it for.

Comment: I created a `data()` property within `App.vue` which return a `isLogin: false`, but in my `Login.vue` in the `login()` method, I call `this.isLogin` which is `undefined`, does I need to do something else in order to have the value correctly passed?

Comment: If you want to use purely a props and data approach like that, then you'll need to pass that `isLogin` property, or prop, from your `App.vue` to your `Login.vue` through whatever hierarchy of components you currently have set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue updates it stuff when it detects that the data it depends on changes. For Vue to detect that it changes, the data needs to be reactive.

Something on the prototype chain is not, and I think you are over-complicating things by using the prototype chain for that. To manage a global state, just use a Vuex store. ([docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/))

You would then use `...mapGetters(['isLoggedIn'])` in your `computed` property, `this.$store.commit('loggedIn', true)` or something along those lines in your Login.vue file.

Comment: Vuex would definitely work here to manage variables accessible to all components, the question is whether or not it's overkill for managing a single var.

Comment: It would surprise me if an application large enough for a login screen does not have more data that would better fit in Vuex.

Comment: No, what @Sumurai8 is proposing is to use Vuex, a state management tool that would allow you to have one or more "store(s)" of variables you could access throughout your application. There's more info about this on [Vuex's website](https://vuex.vuejs.org/#what-is-vuex).

Comment: It's also possible to create your own store pattern as well, if you want to go that route, described [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch), but that could be more trouble than it's worth.